# Blurred overlay effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can do an overlay effect on my elements using the CSS

```
html:after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .6;
    background: #000;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

How can I make a "blurred" overlay effect, in a similar vein to [this](http://css-tricks.com/1820-blurry-background-effect/)? (Note: I do not want to be using images. I would like to blur, for example, a rendered paragraph.)

Comment: That page actually gives you everything you need to make that effect. I'm not sure what more you want...

Comment: For another take on the tutorial in the page you link, it might be worth taking a look at [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/)'s [Complex Spiral demo](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html), which does pretty much exactly the same thing, though his explanation feels more clearly explained.

Comment: @Thor84no: Not really. Have you carefully read the article? Have you carefully read my question? I'm not interested in background images specifically. I'm want a blurry *foreground*, not a blurry *background*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do this:

1.) Use a different background for the whole page and the considered wrapper div.

2.) Use the jQuery `.blurimage` function:

JS:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.blurimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".blurimg").blurimage();
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<img src="test.png" alt="test" class="blurimg">
```

Hope this helps.

[Link to the plugin: [http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blurimage]](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blurimage)

Comment: @Randomblue Just make a `<p>` tag instead of an `<img>` tag :)

Comment: @Randomblue OK with text you just need to use CSS. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rNPus/ Hope it helps :)